# Combining single and double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, heredoc

I'm wondering if JavaScript has a writing format for using html elements that have both single and double quotes inside JavaScript functions. May be something like heredoc for javascript or it could be a function in jQuery.
I couldn't find a solution to my problem and will try to describe it below:

I am writing a web page on php. I have a page and there is a `form` in it. There is a jQuery function that appends `select` elements to a form. After appending, user selects some options and submit the form. (I really wanted to paste a whole code here to make it clearer, but there is a big amount of code which is not so nice, so I tried to simplify it for you, sorry for some bad code)

I have a php variable like this one (`select` has `onchange` event, `showUser` is a function with AJAX request):

```
$string = <<<EOT
<select name="sapak[]" onchange='showUser(this.value, document.getElementsByName("dereje[]")[0].value)'>
EOT;
```

And there are many `option` in between and of course closing `</select>`(I didn't write all the code to be shorter). A part of jQuery function that appends `select` to the `form`:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div> <? echo $string; ?> <a href="#" class="remove_field">Del</a></div>');
```

My problem here is that in `$string` variable I have to use single and double quotes, and when it comes to `append()` function in jQuery I use quotes again. And all these give me error in browser's console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, because of single quotes started at `append('` , but ending at `onchange='` . Is there are any smart solution for this? I thought that heredoc will be, I've googled and I think that actually there is no heredoc for javascript. May be some other formattings available?

Comment: Have you tried `echo addslashes($string)`?

Comment: Have you heard of character escaping?

Comment: @Imperative I've tried it, but ended up again with many quotes : $(wrapper).append('<div> <select name="sapak[]" onchange='showUser(this.value, document.getElementsByName("dereje[]")[0].value)'> </div>');

Comment: I used character escaping at the beginning, but it didn't work. May be I missed something(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$(wrapper).append("<div> <? echo $string; ?> </div>");

$string = <<<EOT
<select name=\"sapak[]\" onchange=\"showUser(this.value, document.getElementsByName('dereje[]')[0].value)\">
EOT;
```

As @Imperative advises about character escaping

Comment: thanks, but still the same error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" : $(wrapper).append("<div> <div><select name=\"sapak[]\" required onchange=\"showUser(this.value, document.getElementsByName('dereje[]')[0].value, ...

Comment: Actually error gone after deleting the <a href="#">. Should I escape "#" also?

Comment: You have to escape every double quotes within your string but not the single quote

Comment: Could I use single quotes on $(wrapper).append('<div> <? echo $string; ?> </div>'); ? I have auto generating code with many double code inside, so I prefer to use single quotes in jQuery function

Comment: Yes you can, in this case, you'll have to escape single quotes within your string.